# combining two plots in r

Tags: r, matrix, plot, heatmap

Here are two plots I intend to combine:

First is half matrix of heatmap plot. ..............................

```
# plot 1 , heatmap plot
set.seed (123)
 myd <- data.frame ( matrix(sample (c(1, 0, -1), 500, replace = "T"), 50))

mmat <-  cor(myd)
diag(mmat) <- NA
mmat[upper.tri (mmat)] <- NA
heatmap (mmat, keep.dendro = F, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA)
```

[image]

I need to suppress the names in x and y columns and put them in diagonal.

The second plot, please note that names / labels in first plot corresponds name in second plot (x1 to X10):

```
  vard <- data.frame ( position = c(1, 10, 15, 18, 20, 23, 24, 30, 35, 40), 
          Names =paste ("X", 1:10, sep = ""))
    plot(vard$position, vard$position - vard$position,
                type = "n", axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = NULL, yaxt = "n")
    polygon(c(0, max(vard$position + 0.08 * max(vard$position)),
                max(vard$position) + 0.08 * max(vard$position),
                0), 0.2 * c(-0.3, -0.3, 0.3, 0.3), col = "green4")
    segments(vard$position, -0.3, vard$position,                0.3)
    text(vard$position, 0.7, vard$position,
                    srt = 90)
    text(vard$position, -0.7, vard$Names)
```

[image]

I intend rotate the first plot so that X1 to X10 should correspond to the same in the second plot and there is connection between labels in second plot to first plot. The output would look like:

[image]
How can I do this ?

**Edits**: based on comments about add = TRUE....I am trying to add polygon to the heatmap plot, the like follows. But I could not find coordinates ..The strategy plot this way and flip the actual figure later...help much appreciated...

[image]

Comment: `labRow=NA, labCol=NA` in your `heatmap` call will get rid of the labels.

Comment: heatmap (mmat, keep.dendro = F, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, labRow=NA, labCol=NA, add = TRUE) will allow to add the second part. You do not need use plot again, just polygon and plot works fine, however you might need to rotate the data of matrix itself to rotate heatmap...i do not have complete solution just hint ..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a fully **grid**-based solution. The only really involved bit is the function `convertToColors()`; it takes a numeric matrix (possibly including NAs) and converts it to sRGB color strings (e.g. `"#FFFFFF`) representing colors on a red-to-white `heat.colors()` scale. Red corresponds to the minimum value in the matrix, white corresponds to the maximum value, and `NA`s are transparent.

Other than that, I think the code does a decent job of showing how many **grid** functions are no more complicated, and considerably more consistent and flexible, than the low-level **base** graphics functions.

```
library(grid)

## Data: heatmap
set.seed (123)
myd <- data.frame ( matrix(sample (c(1, 0, -1), 500, replace = "T"), 50))
mmat <-  cor(myd)
diag(mmat) <- NA
mmat[upper.tri (mmat)] <- NA
## Data: Positions
vard <- c(1, 10, 15, 18, 20, 23, 24, 30, 35, 40)

## Construct a function to convert a numeric matrix to a matrix of color names.
## The lowest value in the matrix maps to red, the highest to white,
## and the NAs to "transparent".
convertToColors <- function(mat) {
    # Produce 'normalized' version of matrix, with values ranging from 0 to 1
    rng <- range(mat, na.rm = TRUE)
    m <- (mat - rng[1])/diff(rng)
    # Convert to a matrix of sRGB color strings
    m2 <- m; class(m2) <- "character"
    m2[!is.na(m2)] <- rgb(colorRamp(heat.colors(10))(m[!is.na(m)]), max = 255)
    m2[is.na(m2)] <- "transparent"
    return(m2)
}

## Initialize plot and prepare two viewports
grid.newpage()
heatmapViewport <- viewport(height=1/sqrt(2), width=1/sqrt(2), angle = -135) 
annotationViewport <- viewport(y = 0.7, height = 0.4)

## Plot heat map
pushViewport(heatmapViewport)
    grid.raster(t(convertToColors(mmat)), interpolate = FALSE)
upViewport()

## Precompute x-locations of text and segment elements
n <- nrow(mmat)
v_x <- vard/max(vard)
X_x <- seq(0, 1, len=n)

## Plot the annotated green bar and line segments
pushViewport(annotationViewport)
    ## Green rectangle
    grid.polygon(x = c(0,0,1,1,0), y = c(.45,.55,.55,.45,.45),
                 gp = gpar(fill = "green4"))
    pushViewport(viewport(width = (n-1)/n))
        ## Segments and text marking vard values
        grid.segments(x0 = v_x, x1 = v_x, y0 = 0.3, y1 = 0.7)
        grid.text(label = vard, x = v_x, y = 0.75, rot = 90)
        ## Text marking heatmap column names (X1-X10)
        grid.text(paste0("X", seq_along(X_x)), x = X_x, y=0.05,
                  gp = gpar(fontface="bold"))
        ## Angled lines
        grid.segments(x0 = v_x, x1 = X_x, y0 = 0.29, y1 = 0.09)
    upViewport()
upViewport()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the smart solution....looks like grid is good things learn and thanks for realizing that too. I have little question here - the arrangements of bars match with the triangle only when there is new plot developed in gui, if any plot is already open of different size then there is mistmatch between the upper rectangle and triangle portion ...

Comment: @jon -- I'm slightly puzzled by that behavior as well. I've edited my code to call `grid.newpage()` instead of `plot.new()`, to emphasize that this requires a fresh plotting device, but I'm not 100% sure why.

Answer (score 11):

This isn't really a full answer, but there are some ideas in it that might help you construct one...

Compared to the **base** graphical system, the **grid** system (on which both `ggplot2` and `lattice` are based) has **much** better support for arranging multiple graphical elements in a compound plot. It uses 'viewports' to specify locations in a plot; viewports of any height, width and degree of rotation can be 'pushed' to any location within an existing plot. Then, once pushed, they can be plotted into and, finally, stepped  up from so that another plot can be placed elsewhere in the main plotting area.

If this were my project, I'd probably work towards a fully **grid**-based solution (making liberal use of higher-level `lattice` or `ggplot2` plots). The `gridBase` package, however, does provide some support for combining **base** and **grid** graphics, and I've used that in the example below.

(For more details on what I've done in the following, see the `grid.pdf`, `viewports.pdf`, and `rotated.pdf` vignettes located in `file.path(.Library, "grid", "doc")`, as well as the vignette that is opened by typing `vignette("gridBase", package="gridBase")`).

```
## Load required packages
library(lattice); library(grid); library(gridBase)

## Construct example dataset
set.seed (123)
myd <- data.frame ( matrix(sample (c(1, 0, -1), 500, replace = "T"), 50))
mmat <-  cor(myd)
diag(mmat) <- NA
mmat[upper.tri (mmat)] <- NA

## Reformat data for input to `lattice::levelplot()`
grid <- data.frame(expand.grid(x = rownames(mmat), y = colnames(mmat)), 
                   z = as.vector(mmat))

## Open a plotting device    
plot.new()     

## Push viewport that will contain the levelplot; plot it; up viewport.
pushViewport(viewport(y = 0.6, height = 0.8, width = 0.8, angle=135))
    lp <- levelplot(z~y*x, grid, colorkey=FALSE, 
                    col.regions=heat.colors(100), aspect=1,
                    scales = list(draw=FALSE), xlab="", ylab="", 
                    par.settings=list(axis.line=list(col="white")))
    plot(lp, newpage=FALSE)
upViewport()

## Push viewport that will contain the green bar; plot it; up viewport.
pushViewport(viewport(y = 0.7, height=0.2))
    # Use the gridBase::gridOMI to determine the location within the plot.
    # occupied by the current viewport, then set that location via par() call
    par(omi = gridOMI(), new=TRUE, mar = c(0,0,0,0))
    plot(0:1, 0:1,type = "n", axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "", yaxt = "n")
    polygon(x=c(0,0,1,1,0), y = c(.4,.6,.6,.4,.4), col = "green4")
upViewport()
```

[image]

Comment: you probably want to use `upViewport` rather than pop, if you want to be able to navigate back to the location.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien thanks alot solution and for the ideas...as you said this can be point to start with particularly the later section need to be done :  text(vard$position, 0.7, vard$position,  srt = 90), text(vard$position, -0.7, vard$Names)

Comment: @baptiste -- Good point. Since there's no compensating advantage to using `popViewport()`, I should train myself to default to `upViewport()`. I'll start by editing the answer above ;)

Comment: I accidently awarded bounty (can not be undone) to this answer rather other complete answer, fortunately from the same author....

Comment: Oh -- I just assumed you were wanting to treat both of us equitably :=)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an error in this line of code:

```
myd <- data.frame ( matrix(sample (c(1, 0, -1), 500, replace = "T"), 50))
```

Solved by replacing "T" with `TRUE` (No quotes)