# Make a rectangular legend, with rows and columns labeled, in grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, r-grid

I've got a ggplot where I'm mapping factors to both fill and alpha, like this:

```
set.seed(47)
the_data <- data.frame(value = rpois(6, lambda=20),
                       cat1 = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3),
                       cat2 = rep(c("X", "Y", "Z"), 2))

ggplot(the_data, aes(y = value, x = cat2, alpha = cat1, fill = cat2)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.5, 1)) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

The people I'm producing it for don't find the legend for alpha very clear. I think a good alternative would be something like this (which I hacked together in base graphics):

[image]

I know I can't generate a legend like that with high-level ggplot commands, but can I do it in `grid` and put it on top of my plot?

Comment: The quickest solution might be to just use two **grid** viewports to allocate separate regions for the plot and its legend, then use the **gridBase** package to place your hand-made legend in the upper viewport. (`vignette("gridBase")` gives an intro, or search for `[r] gridBase` here on SO for additional examples.)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Didn't know about `gridBase`, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Yeah, it occasionally comes in very handy.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489447/combining-two-plots-in-r/11496362#11496362) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985013/how-do-you-draw-a-line-across-a-multiple-figure-environment-in-r/9985936#9985936) are  a couple of  places where I've used it to accomplish otherwise tricky effects.

Comment: If I were to do this again, I'd probably [make a little ggplot for the legend as in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32575342/903061).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is one possible starting point. I create two different plots which have the appropriate legends - a 'bright' and a 'pale'. Extract the legends from the plot objects. Then use `grid` `viewport`s, one for the plot, and one for each legend, to put the pieces together.

```
library(grid)
library(gtable)

# create plot with legend with alpha = 1
g1 <- ggplot(the_data, aes(y = value, x = cat2, alpha = cat1, fill = cat2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.5, 1)) +
  theme_bw() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "A",
                             title.hjust = 0.4),
         alpha = FALSE) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.text = element_blank())

g1

# grab legend
legend_g1 <- gtable_filter(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1)), "guide-box") 


# create plot with 'pale' legend
g2 <- ggplot(the_data, aes(y = value, x = cat2, alpha = cat1, fill = cat2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.5, 1)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 0.5),
                             title = "B",
                             title.hjust = 0.3),
         alpha = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
g2

# grab legend
legend_g2 <- gtable_filter(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g2)), "guide-box") 



# arrange plot and legends

# legends to the right

# define plotting regions (viewports)
vp_plot <- viewport(x = 0.4, y = 0.5,
                    width = 0.8, height = 1)

vp_legend_g1 <- viewport(x = 0.85, y = 0.5,
                           width = 0.4, height = 0.4)

vp_legend_g2 <- viewport(x = 0.90, y = 0.5,
                           width = 0.4, height = 0.4)


# clear current device
grid.newpage()

# add objects to the viewports
# plot without legend
print(g1 + theme(legend.position = "none"), vp = vp_plot)
upViewport(0)

pushViewport(vp_legend_g1)
grid.draw(legend_g1)
upViewport(0)

pushViewport(vp_legend_g2)
grid.draw(legend_g2)
```

[image]

```
# legends on top
vp_plot <- viewport(x = 0.5, y = 0.4,
                    width = 1, height = 0.85)

vp_legend_g1 <- viewport(x = 0.5, y = 0.9,
                         width = 0.4, height = 0.4)

vp_legend_g2 <- viewport(x = 0.55, y = 0.9,
                         width = 0.4, height = 0.4)

grid.newpage()

print(g1 + theme(legend.position = "none"), vp = vp_plot)
upViewport(0)

pushViewport(vp_legend_g1)
grid.draw(legend_g1)
upViewport(0)

pushViewport(vp_legend_g2)
grid.draw(legend_g2)
```

[image]

Comment: Well after all that I certainly do need to give you a vote, but Josh's strategy now seems even more appropriate.

Comment: This is beautiful! Thanks, Henrik.

Answer (score 4):

@Henrik

This might be a little easier,

```
g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
g2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)

leg1 <- gtable_filter(g1, "guide-box") 
leg2 <- gtable_filter(g2, "guide-box") 
leg <- gtable:::cbind_gtable(leg1[["grobs"]][[1]],  leg2[["grobs"]][[1]], "first")

g1$grobs[g1$layout$name == "guide-box"][[1]] <- leg
g1$widths[max(subset(g1$layout, name == "guide-box")[["r"]])] <- list(leg1$width + leg2$width)

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g1)
```