# 'Merging' two plots using ggplot2 and R

Tags: r, plot

Given the following dataset:

```
data = cbind(1:10,c('open','reopen','closed'),letters[1:3],1:10)
data = rbind(data,cbind(1:10,c('open','closed','reopen'),letters[1:3],5:10))
data = rbind(data,cbind(1:10,c('closed','open','reopen'),letters[1:3],3:10))
data = data.frame(data);
colnames(data) <- c("id","status","author","when")
```

I'd like to get a plot similar to the following:

```
ggplot(data, aes(when,id)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = id,colour = status)) +
  geom_point(aes(group = id,colour = author))
```

But, as such I get a single legend by 'author' with the status and author values. How can I get the same result but with a legend for author and other for status? My rationale is that I want to layer two plots of the same dataset on top of each other.
[image: Plot example]

Comment: You would probably be better off using `+geom_point(aes(shape = status))` to use different markers for different status.

Comment: I tried that, but shapes are limited to six different values, and the status set is larger. I'm trying to achieve the same effect but using colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can have different color scales / legends for one ggplot. You could hack something together ([see this question for legend hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20129299/903061)), but in this case where one of your geom's is point, you could just use `fill` and one of the point options that are filled in.

```
ggplot(data, aes(when,id)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = id,colour = status)) +
  geom_point(aes(group = id, fill = author),
             shape = 21, color = NA, size = 4)
```

Here the colors used are the same for each, but you can edit the color or fill scales individually, e.g., adding

```
 scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual") +
 scale_color_brewer(type = "qual", palette = 2)
```

[image: plot]

I do agree with AndyClifton that using color in two ways will be hard to distinguish. You could also experiment with line types, point shapes, or even plotting with `geom_text` using a word, a letter, or a number as a label instead of points. You say you have more than 6 values for author, but it will be very difficult to distinguish more than 6 colors for author, *especially* when color is also being used for status.

Comment: Thanks Gregor. I agree the result probably won't be very good with default values ggplot values but I was hoping to work that out tweaking line size and point size.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take your data. First you should be aware that you have a problem that your `when` and `id` column is a string, so you are plotting 1, 10, 2, 3, ... not 1,...9,10. We can fix that:

```
data$when.num <-as.numeric(as.character(data$when))
data$id.num <-as.numeric(as.character(data$id))
```

Then we'll plot it but use different shapes to get two different legends:

```
require(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = when.num, y = id)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = id,colour = status)) +
  geom_point(aes(group = id,shape = author))

print(p)
```

And you get this:

[image]

I think this is much clearer than using coloured points for the author, but this is a question of taste.

Comment: Thanks Andy for the response. The thing is the shape scale is limited to 6 different values, and my author column is larger. I also tried with size but the result wasn`t very pleasing.

Comment: it might be worth giving us a more realistic data set to play with?