# Creating a choropleth (polygon) map with 2 dimensional values using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

**I would like to create a choropleth map visualising 2 dimensional values (= color fill the polygons according to an ordered pair `(v1, v2)`, where `v1` and `v2` are ordered factors).**

Here is an example of how the result should look like:
[image]

I think the color matrix legend with the two dimensions makes it clear what I want to achieve.

I would like to implement this using `ggplot2::geom_polygon`.

---

*Minimal example:*

```
ids <- factor(c("1.1", "2.1", "1.2", "2.2", "1.3", "2.3"))

values <- data.frame(
    id = ids,
    v1 = factor(c("Hi","Med","Med","Hi","Lo","Lo"), 
                levels=c("Lo", "Med", "Hi"), ordered=TRUE),
    v2 = factor(c("Hi","Lo","Lo","Med","Med","Hi"), 
                levels=c("Lo", "Med", "Hi"), ordered=TRUE))

positions <- data.frame(
  id = rep(ids, each = 4),
  x = c(2, 1, 1.1, 2.2, 1, 0, 0.3, 1.1, 2.2, 1.1, 1.2, 2.5, 1.1, 0.3,
        0.5, 1.2, 2.5, 1.2, 1.3, 2.7, 1.2, 0.5, 0.6, 1.3),
  y = c(-0.5, 0, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 2.1, 1.7, 1, 1.5,
        2.2, 2.1, 1.7, 2.1, 3.2, 2.8, 2.1, 2.2, 3.3, 3.2))

datapoly <- merge(values, positions, by=c("id"))
```

I would like to combine the two following maps in just one following the example above. The color fill of the polgons should be according to the ordered pair `(v1, v2)` and of course I would need a color matrix legend.

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(datapoly, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_polygon(aes(fill=v1, group=id))
ggplot(datapoly, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_polygon(aes(fill=v2, group=id))
```

[image]

Comment: I asked a similar question a while ago - focused purely on the 2-dimensional legend idea: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20129299/903061

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit late to the party here, but, for the benefit of anyone coming across this question later, https://github.com/wmurphyrd/colorplaner seems to do exactly what you want.  The second example in the [usage](https://github.com/wmurphyrd/colorplaner#usage) section even gives an example of coloring in a map.

Answer (score -1):

How about `interaction(v1, v2)` and map a single scale on the resulting interaction?

```
# using your inputs
values$v1_2 <- interaction(values$v1, values$v2)
...
datapoly <- merge(values, positions, by=c("id"))

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(RColorBrewer)
ggplot(datapoly, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_polygon(aes(fill=v1_2, group=id)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette= "Blues")
```

[image]

Or use the solution @gregor linked to in the comments above.

Comment: mh, i really would like to have a matrix legend and not a single scale...The link @gregor posted above definately goes into the right direction...